# How may I put a $_POST data into a database table?

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

It's been 3 weeks since I've started to learn symfony 4. I am trying to put the chosen data from the dropdown list into a database but I am not using a `Form builder` - the data is entered in html/twig and then stored into a variable `$value`.

I am wondering, though, how can I put this data from the variable `$value` into a database of choice (table User)? I mean, (if understood it right) when I use the form builder I am supposed to use ObjectManager `$manager` as following:

```
$manager->persist($value);
$manager->flush();
```

In this case I, honestly, have no idea of how I can put my data into a database.
Can anyone give me a clue?

**twig**

```
<select name="user">
    {% for user in users %}
        <option value="{{ user.idUser }},{{ user.name }}" label="{{ user.name }} {{ user.surname }}">{{ user.name }} {{ user.surname }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<button type="submit" id="article_form_save" name="article_form[save]">ADD</button>
```

**controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/attribution", name="attribution")
 */
public function create (Request $request) {

    $users = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class)
        ->findAll();


    $value = $_POST;  

    dump($value);

  return $this->render('database/Roles/attrib.html.twig', [
         'users' => $users
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access your dropdown data from `$_POST['user']` or you can use `$request->request->get('user')`

In order to save data into the database, you can create an object (Post for example) where you set the values you are retrieving from the request and then saving them.

You can do something like this:

```
 <?php
 /**
 * @Route("/attribution", name="attribution")
 */
public function create (Request $request) {

    $users = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class)
        ->findAll();

    $user = $request->request->get('user');

    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $post = new Post();

    $post->setUser($user); // I suppose the user property in your post is just an integer not an object

    $manager->persist($post);
    $manager->flush();
    dump($user);

  return $this->render('database/Roles/attrib.html.twig', [
         'users' => $users
    ]);        

?>
```

This is just an example, which you can adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your value should have only the user id. Change

```
<option value="{{ user.idUser }},{{ user.name }}"
```

to

```
<option value="{{ user.idUser }}"
```

Then, you can get the user like this:

```
$userId = $request->request->get('user'); //this will not be a user entity, but only an id
```

Which will return the user id.

Then you need to retrieve the user via your repository and save it.

1. Inject your user repository and entity manager by type-hinting them in your function arguments:

   public function create (Request $request, UserRepository $repository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
2. do a findOneBy:

   $user = $repository->findOneBy(['id' => $userId]);
3. Set the user to the article and save it

   $article.setUser($user);
   $entityManager->persist($article);
   $entityManager->flush();

PS: using Symfony forms would make it waaay simpler.